# Determinant of the Hessian matrix where all second derivatives have no variables

Tags: calculus

First time posting. I've come across a little problem.

For,

$$f(x) = 3x^2+2y^2+3x-1$$

I have found the following partial derivatives:
\begin{align}
f_x &= 6x + 3 \\
f_y &= 4y\\
f_{xx} &= 6\\
f_{yy} &= 4\\
f_{xy} &= f_{yx} =  0  \\
\end{align}

Which gives the Hessian matrix:

$$
        H = \begin{pmatrix}
        6 & 0 \\
        0 & 4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Therefore,

$\det H(x,y) = (6\times 4) - (0)^2$ = 24

The questions asks to check the point $\det  H(-1/2, 0) > 0$

I take it this can't be done, so I must have gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: Did you mean $f(x,y)$ at the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done the problem. You have shown $\det H(x,y) > 0$ for all $x,y$. It definitely holds for the point $-1/2, 0$.

Comment: Oh I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have definitely solved the problem well. The main thing to note is that the elements of your hessian matrix are not functions of $x$ and $y$.  So you cannot evaluate $H(x,y)$ using $H(-1/2,0)$, by substituting in $H(x,y)$. However, if you go back to an intermediate step that you have not shown -- which is setting the first partials to zero, 
you will find that $6x+3=0$, hence $x=-1/2$
similarly, $4y=0$, therefore $y=0$.
Now that your Hessian determinant $H(x,y)=24 >0$, suggests that your solution is for $H(-1/2,0)$. Sorry for the long answer.
Out of interest, where you asked to check whether the function is at a maximum or minimum? Have a great day.

Comment: You can evaluate $H(x,y)$ by substituting in; it just happens to be a constant function in this case.

Comment: [See this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to write mathematical formulas in questions and answers on this site.